# Two or more controllers sharing same voting action (just the model class differing) - how to create a mixin to be included in all controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to create some generic code and reuse it across several controllers. Basically I'm using the thumbs_up gem which allows some models to act as voteable and other models to act as voter (user model, for instance).

Imagine the following scenario:

I have the Question and Answer models. Question has many answers. Both question and answer are voteable.

Routes.rb:

```
resources :questions do

    resources :answers do

      member do
        get 'vote_up'
        get 'vote_down'
      end

    end

    member do
      get 'vote_up'
      get 'vote_down'
    end

  end
```

I've implemented a solution where each of my voteable models have their own controllers where the vote_up and vote_down actions are processed. However, in both controllers these actions are basically the same, the only difference being the model class used to find the instance to be voted on. Example:

QuestionsContoller:

```
  def vote_up
    @voteable = Question.find(params[:id])

    current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@voteable)  

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :action => 'votes/vote_completed' }
    end
  end
```

AnswersContoller:

```
  def vote_up
    @voteable = Answer.find(params[:id])

    current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@voteable)  

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :action => 'votes/vote_completed' }
    end
  end
```

I would like to create a mixin with this code to be included in both controllers, can anyone shed some light on how to implement it? Should the mixin define the vote_up and vote_down methods? Or instead, should the mixin implement some auxiliary method which then is called in the vote_up and vote_down methods of each controller?

Is this the best approach for this problem or should there only be one single controller to handle the vote_up and vote_down actions?

I would very much appreciate your help on these matters.
Many thanks in advance

Bruno

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd rather go the polymorphic way but for your mixin (module) a solution can be this:

Questions Controller

```
include Voting
```

Voting Module:

```
module Voting
  def vote_up
    @voteable = Object.const_get(self.class.to_s.chomp('Controller').singularize).find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@voteable)  

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :action => 'votes/vote_completed' }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi tommasop, thanks for your quick reply. I've tried that approach, however I always get the following error: NoMethodError (undefined method `find' for QuestionsController:Class): lib/voting.rb:3:in `vote_up'. I've included voting on my QuestionsController and removed the vote_up method from there.

Comment: Updated answer, can you try this new approach? Thanks

Comment: Just a note — `self.class.to_s.chomp('Controller')` is quite a bit faster than using `gsub`. It's a better option anytime you need to *chomp* a set of characters off the end of a string.

Comment: Hi tommasop and coreyward, it worked perfectly. Thanks!! Now I just need to figure out a nicer way to create the vote_up and vote_down routes for the members of voteable models. Is it possible to do some meta programming on the routes file, so that we could inject the get 'vote_up' and get 'vote_down' routes using a single line of code? Many thanks!

Comment: You can also just call `.constantize` on the string instead of `Object.const_get`

Comment: Hi Bruno, can you elaborate on the routes issue (or post another question)?